# Running .app by double click on it and linking dylibs

Tags: cocoa, dylib, xcode4.6

Could someone tell me how to launch(run) .app(mac executable) by directly double clicking on it without running through xcode.And I tried with cocoa application, how to link or load depedendent dylibs for .app.

And how to give relative path of dylibs in info.plist using DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

It seem like that you could run it by directly double clicking when you Archive it and "Export As Appellation" in the Organizer, and end , you could copy it to anywhere to run.

by the way, when you first double click it on a Mac which first time to launch this app, it will not run only if you use "open" in the right-key menu to launch it , then, it will work as you want.